# My sub menu is still not working properly (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a sub menu using jquery. I have made the code as below. But there is still something that is not working properly. What I want is, when the start, the menu is closed. Currently, all menus are open. How do I do it, can anyone help me?

```js
$('.list-menu > li').click(function () {
    var child = $(this).children('ul');
    
    if(child.length===0){
       $(this).children().addClass("active");
       return;
     }
     
     $('.list-menu ul').not(child).slideUp('normal');
     child.slideDown('normal');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-menu">
        <li class="menu-1">
            <a href="#">Getting Started</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li id="sub-1"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="sub-2"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-2">
            <a href="#">Controlling How Data is Indexed</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li id="sub-3"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="sub-4"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-3">
            <a href="#">Uploading and Indexing Data</a>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li id="sub-5"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
                </li>
                <li id="sub-6"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Querying For More Information
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Put this line `$(".submenu").hide()` on page load.

Comment: @Swati it's far better practice to use CSS to set the initial UI state as it avoids the FOUC which can occur when setting it through JS, which has to wait for the DOM to load first.

Comment: Yes i agree with you @RoryMcCrossan :) .

Answer (score 1):

You can set the child `ul` elements to `display: none` on page load using CSS:

```css
ul > li > ul { display: none; }
```

```js
$('.list-menu > li').click(function() {
  var child = $(this).children('ul');
  $(this).children().addClass("active");

  $('.list-menu ul').not(child).slideUp('normal');
  child.slideToggle('normal');
});
```

```css
ul > li > ul { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="list-menu">
  <li class="menu-1">
    <a href="#">Getting Started</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li id="sub-1"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="sub-2"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-2">
    <a href="#">Controlling How Data is Indexed</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li id="sub-3"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="sub-4"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-3">
    <a href="#">Uploading and Indexing Data</a>
    <ul class="submenu">
      <li id="sub-5"><a href="#">Child 1</a>
      </li>
      <li id="sub-6"><a href="#">Child 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Querying For More Information</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when I click the getting started menu, the menu will open. but when I click to close it can't. How to?

Comment: To do that change `slideDown()` to `slideToggle()`. I updated the answer for you. Also note that the `if` statement checking the number of children is redundant so it can be removed along with the `return` statement.

Comment: No problem, glad to help